# Backbone listenTo does not fire for property change

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm kind of new to Backbone and I have some code that is supposed to listen to a property change and trigger a function. Everything I'm seeing online about how to use listenTo seems to cover this exact situation so I don't know what I'm overlooking.

To try to get a better understanding I made a much less complicated sample that just contains a model, a view and sets up the listenTo. The problem still arises in that smaller sample.

I've put some code in to log which functions are being fired and in what order. When I see when running this code is pretty much the order that I expect, except that onSomethingChanged is never called.

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:hasName', this.onSomethingChanged);

        $('#steps').append('<li>AppView initialize</li>');
        this.model.setName('Test Name');
    },
    onSomethingChanged: function(){
        $('#steps').append('<li>AppView onSomethingChanged</li>');
    }
});

var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.bind('change:name', this.onNameChanged, this);
        this.set({'name': 'Nothing'});

        $('#steps').append('<li>SomeModel initialize</li>');
    },
    onNameChanged: function(status, name){
        this.set({'hasName': name != null});

        $('#steps').append('<li>SomeModel onNameChanged</li>');
    },
    setName: function(name){
        this.set({'name': name});

        $('#steps').append('<li>SomeModel setName</li>');
    }
});

$(function(){
    window.app = new AppView({model: new SomeModel()});
});
```

I've set it up in a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hamveefz and it shows the order as this:

1. SomeModel onNameChanged
2. SomeModel initialize
3. AppView initialize
4. SomeModel onNameChanged
5. SomeModel setName

I assumed that in SomeModel's onNameChanged function where it then does a 'this.set' with the hasName property would automatically cause the listener for changes to hasName to be invoked.

Can someone explain to me where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `set` doesn't necessarily change anything. For example, this:

```
model.set('property', model.get('property'));
```

won't trigger a `'change'` event because it doesn't actually do anything.

Your model's `initialize` sets the name:

```
this.set({'name': 'Nothing'});
```

The `'change:name'` handler is bound by that point so `onNameChanged` will be called and `hasName` will be set to `true`.

Then the view is built and its `initialize` will:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:hasName', this.onSomethingChanged);
this.model.setName('Test Name');
```

You're thinking that `setName` should trigger the `'change:hasName'` event but it won't. The `hasName` attribute will already be `true` at this point and you'll be doing a `set('hasName', true)` so it won't change.

You'd be better off leaving the `name` as `null` or `undefined` until it actually gets set. You'd remove the `this.set({'name': 'Nothing'});` from the model's `initialize` and add:

```
defaults: {
    name: null,
    hasName: false
}
```

Then adjust to view (and its template) to handle the "no name" case.